# X-FRAME ALLOW-FROM https://www.example.com

Tags: linux, apache

When I add this line

```
X-FRAME ALLOW-FROM https://www.example.com
```

in the config files of apache2.conf in my ubuntu 14.04 server. It fails to start my apache. Can any one tell the exact line that can be added to allow X-FRAME from only one url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean:

```
Header set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "ALLOW-FROM https://www.example.com"
```

But honestly you're so far off from correct syntax it's really unclear what your intent was.  You'll need mod_headers loaded.

Comment: Thanks it worked, However I used always append  instead of set.

Header always append X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://xxx.yyy.com"

I was missing the double quotes which is why it was not working. It was no where in documentation.